# How to import files in bash from a different folder

Tags: bash

my project looks like this:

```
helper/
      helper_func.sh
main/
      my_program.sh
```

How do I import `helper_func.sh` in `my_program.sh`. If all files are in the same folder I just do `source helper_func.sh` and I can import the functions but if I do `source ../helper/helper_func.sh` it can't seem to find it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

".." is relative to the present working directory, not relative to the script's source code. So it depends what directory you run the script from. Which makes it a bad idea because you generally can't know where someone will run a script from.

One possible trick to use is $0 which generally should contain the location of the script. So...

```
source `dirname $0`/../helper/helper_func.sh
```

might do what you want, but you'll have to experiment.